# AWS S3 SSE : s3 managed keys encrypted object upload using python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

I am simply trying to upload encrypted object to S3 bucket.
I have gone through the AWS documentation on SSE.
Most confusing part is I am not clear on :
1. If we need to set default server side encryption option to AES256(I am assuming it is S3 managed key) for bucket before uploading object to s3 
or
2. we can directly upload to s3 bucket without having any server side encryption option set for that bucket?

Assuming second point true, I have tried to upload object on S3 specifying extra arguments:

```
s3_con.upload_file('abc.txt','s3_key_path/abc.txt',ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "AES256"})
```

I was able to upload file using above code line but the file was not encrypted.
So I guess I need to try first point before uploading to bucket.

How can I upload encrypted object using server side encryption using S3 managed key in python and what steps I need to do for this?

Comment: What makes you say the file was not encrypted after upload?

Comment: @jarmod I am not sure how to check it is encrypted.But when I opened that file I could see all its contents as is as before uploading.

Comment: Can you please guide me on this if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

The file is encrypted. Look at the Properties > Encryption tab in the AWS console for that S3 object.

You can see the contents because SSE-S3 (AES-256) is transparent at-rest encryption. S3 encrypts the object as it's written to disk, and decrypts it as it's read from disk. Because you have permission to get the object, that process is transparent to you.

You also have other encryption options including KMS managed keys, your own managed keys, and doing client-side encryption prior to sending to S3.

Comment: So there is no need to enable default SSE option for S3 bucket? We can directly encrypt object with various ways like S3 managed keys,customer managed keys and kms and directly upload it to the S3 bucket that don't have any encryption option set?

Comment: The server-side options of SSE-KMS and SSE-S3 (AES256) are mutually exclusive. You can do ciient-side encryption as many times as you like, and you can enable the SSE options at the same time, if you want (multiple layers of encryption). See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingEncryption.html for more.